# How do I load preload associations when creating a database record?

Tags: json, go, go-gorm

I have the following code

```
func Employees(db *database.Database) fiber.Handler {
    return func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {

        var employees []model.Employee

        if response := db.Preload(clause.Associations).Find(&employees); response.Error != nil {
            return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordNotFoundError())
        }

        return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordsFoundSuccess(employees, len(employees)))
    }
}

func CreateEmployee(db *database.Database) fiber.Handler {
    return func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        employee := new(model.Employee)

        if err := c.BodyParser(employee); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%v", err)
            return c.JSON(responseKit.ParsingError())
        }

        // if err := employee.Validate(); err != nil {
        //  return c.JSON(responseKit.ValidationError(err))
        // }

        if result := db.Preload(clause.Associations).Omit(clause.Associations).Create(&employee); result.Error != nil {
            return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordCreateError())
        }

        return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordCreateSuccess(employee))
    }
}
```

Where I preload all the associations when finding employees. This works as expected and I get the employees with their associations preloaded. Where the associations look like this in the response json

```
    "groupID": 1,
    "group": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Test"
    },
    "roleID": 1,
    "role": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Test"
    }
```

But when I create an employee preloading doesn't work. So the response I get back has no group or role data only the ID

```
"groupID": 1,
"group": {
    "id": 0,
    "title": ""
},
"roleID": 1,
"role": {
    "id": 0,
    "title": ""
}
```

This is my employee model

```
type Employee struct {
    PrivateGormModel
    Person      `gorm:"embedded" json:"person,omitempty"`
    Contact     `gorm:"embedded" json:"contact,omitempty"`
    Address     `gorm:"embedded" json:"address,omitempty"`
    AltContact  `gorm:"embedded" json:"privateContact,omitempty"`
    BankAccount `gorm:"embedded" json:"bankAccount,omitempty"`
    GroupID     uint          `json:"groupID"`
    Group       EmployeeGroup `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;" json:"group"`
    RoleID      uint          `json:"roleID"`
    Role        EmployeeRole  `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;" json:"role"`
}
```

How can I preload the data when I create the entry? In this case the group and role already have entries in the database so I create the employee entry with an ID that points to that role and group. I do that with the following json

```
{
    "person":{
        "initials":"",
        "firstName":"",
        "middleName":"",
        "lastName":"",
        "dateOfBirth":"",
        "language":""
    },
    "address":{
        "country":"",
        "zip":"",
        "number":"0",
        "addition":"",
        "street":"",
        "state":"",
        "city":""
    },
    "contact":{
        "tel":"",
        "mail":"",
        "url":""
    },
    "bankAccount":{
        "bank":"",
        "bic":"",
        "iban":"",
        "accountHolder":"",
        "establishment":""
    },
    "roleID":1,
    "groupID":1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not working because, you have omitted `clause.Associations` in CreateEmployee Function

- existing snippet \/

```
if result := db.Preload(clause.Associations).Omit(clause.Associations).Create(&employee); result.Error != nil {
            return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordCreateError())
        }
```

- new snippet \/

```
if result := db.Preload(clause.Associations).Create(&employee); result.Error != nil {
            return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordCreateError())
        }
```

- Edit

```
if result := db.Preload(clause.Associations).Find(&employee); result.Error != nil {
            return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordCreateError())
        }
```

Comment: But If I don't Omit it will create new entries for the role and group right? That is not the behaviour I am looking for.

Comment: I tried without the Omit but it produces the same response

Comment: i edited answer, try preloading after creating employee it will work i think

Comment: So I have to find it after I create it? Isn't that a extra database call? And can it be prevented?

Comment: Yes, just remove preload at create(&employee)

Comment: It works but aren't I making extra database call to find it after I create it? Is there a way to prevent this and do it with just the create?

Comment: yes buddy you have to call extra database call

Comment: To put it simply, Preload does nothing when calling Create, it's only meant to be used when retrieving data.